# Get node list from random walk in networkX

Tags: python, graph, machine-learning, statistics, networkx

I am new to networkX. I created a graph as follows:

```
G = nx.read_edgelist(filename,
                     nodetype=int,
                     delimiter=',',
                     data=(('weight', float),))
```

where the edges are positive, but do not sum up to one.

Is there a built-in method that makes a random walk of `k` steps from a certain node and return the node list? If not, what is the easiest way of doing it (nodes can repeat)?

Pseudo-code:

```
node = random
res = [node]
for i in range(0, k)
    read edge weights from this node
    an edge from this node has probability weight / sum_weights
    node = pick an edge from this node 
    res.append(node)
```

Answer (score 12):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of the package presented below.

I was surprised to see no library do it efficiently, so I've built and open-sourced a python package just for that. It's written in C++ and use parallelization for maximum speed. It can generate millions of random walks in a few seconds.

```
import walker

walks = walker.random_walks(G, n_walks=15, walk_len=10)
```

This will create 15 walks **for each node in your graph G** of length 10.

If you only wish to create one random walk starting from a single node :

```
node = 42
walks = walker.random_walks(G, n_walks=1, walk_len=10, start_node=[node])
```

You can also create node2vec-biased random walks by specifying the **p** and **q** arguments.

Installation needs pybind11 to allow C++ bindings :

```
pip install pybind11
pip install graph-walker
```

Comment: This actually is crazy fast! I ran it on a graph with 20k nodes and 100k edges, returning 1 Million walks each of length 20 in less than a second. Nice Work!

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way of doing it is by using the transition matrix **T** and then using a plain Markovian random walk (in brief, the graph can be considered as a finite-state Markov chain).

Let **A** and **D** be the adjacency and degree matrices of a graph *G*, respectively. The transition matrix **T** is defined as **T** = **D**^(-1) **A**.
Let **p**^(0) be the state vector (in brief, the *i*-th component indicates the probability of being at node *i*) at the beginning of the walk, the first step (walk) can be evaluated as **p**^(1) = **T** **p**^(0).
Iteratively, the *k*-th random walk step can be evaluated as **p**^(k) = **T** **p**^(k-1).

In plain Networkx terms...

```
import networkx
import numpy
# let's generate a graph G
G = networkx.gnp_random_graph(5, 0.5)
# let networkx return the adjacency matrix A
A = networkx.adj_matrix(G)
A = A.todense()
A = numpy.array(A, dtype = numpy.float64)
# let's evaluate the degree matrix D
D = numpy.diag(numpy.sum(A, axis=0))
# ...and the transition matrix T
T = numpy.dot(numpy.linalg.inv(D),A)
# let's define the random walk length, say 10
walkLength = 10
# define the starting node, say the 0-th
p = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0]).reshape(-1,1)
visited = list()
for k in range(walkLength):
    # evaluate the next state vector
    p = numpy.dot(T,p)
    # choose the node with higher probability as the visited node
    visited.append(numpy.argmax(p))
```

Comment: You might not want to invert that diagonal matrix or do a full matrix-matrix multiply.  Consider something like dinv = 1./numpy.sum(A, axis=0).  Then loop over the rows and apply each element of dinv.

Comment: Beautiful, though it seems to me that getting the transition matrix $T$ from the adjacency matrix $A$ is simply a matter of dividing each row by its sum. This is essentially saying that it is equally likely to take each edge of the graph. In fact, we could introduce any weighting scheme and divide by the sum of the edge weights in such an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @lericson This is indeed true. Your first observation holds because the adjacency matrix in my example is binary (i.e., there is a 1 in position _i,j_ if there is an edge between nodes _i_ and _j_). However, it is well known that the adjacency matrix can score in position _i,j_ the weight of the edge linking nodes _i_ and _j_. So the degree matrix D will not contain "the number of nodes attached to a given node", but the sum of the weights of the edges which involve a given node. Hence, your conclusion: in building T, one divides by the sum of the weights.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way of doing it is to use the transition matrix of a graph in CSR sparse format and, of course, there is a great package for that: csrgraph (`pip install csrgraph`). Here is how you can do it:

```
import csrgraph as cg
import numpy as np

G = cg.csrgraph(G, threads=12) 
node_names = G.names
walks = G.random_walks(walklen=10, # length of the walks
                epochs=100, # how many times to start a walk from each node
                start_nodes=None, # the starting node. It is either a list (e.g., [2,3]) or None. If None it does it on all nodes and returns epochs*G.number_of_nodes() walks
                return_weight=1.,
                neighbor_weight=1.)
```

The result is an array of size (epochs*number_of_nodes, walklen). More info on the function and its parameters can be found [here](https://github.com/VHRanger/CSRGraph/blob/adf2c778b5421b4869fa23f580e9f9f91fc8438a/csrgraph/graph.py#L188).

On a graph of 2,130 nodes and 36,560 edges, it took me 0.5 seconds to generate 213,000 paths of length 20 with the snippet above:

```
>>> array([[   0,    4, 1678, ...,   48,  728,   30],
       [   1,   57,  102, ...,  947,  456,  240],
       [   2,  156,  177, ...,  175, 1363,  539],
       ...,
       [2127, 1655, 1656, ..., 1655, 1656, 2127],
       [2128,    4, 1432, ...,  111,   32,  162],
       [2129,    4,  521, ..., 1280,  180,  608]], dtype=uint32)

walks.shape
>>> (213000, 20)
```

The node names can be mapped back to their original format using the snippet below or other similar methods:

```
walks = np.vectorize(lambda x: node_names[x])(walks) # map to original node names
```

NOTE: This package does much more than just random walks, you might want to check their GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/VHRanger/CSRGraph)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer of @AlessioX

Let A be an adjacency matrix, i.e. one where A_ij is 1.0 if there is an edge between vertices i and j, and 0.0 if there is not. (Though note that the below works even for a weighted adjacency matrix.)

```py
>>> A
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Then we can find the transition matrix T by dividing each row by its sum, simply:

```py
>>> A / A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[0.5       , 0.        , 0.5       ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adjacency matrix. Then you can normalise it so that the sum of rows equals 1 and each row is the probability distribution of the node jumping to another node.
You can also have a jump probability if the walker jumps to a random node.

```
M = nx.adjacency_matrix(g) #obtain the adj. matrix for the graph
#normalise the adjacency matrix
for i in range(M.shape[1]):
    if (np.sum(M[i]) > 0):
    M[i] = M[i]/np.sum(M[i])
p = generate a random number between 0 and 1
if p < restart_prob:
    #do restart
else:
    #choose next node
```

Then you can choose a node randomly, then choose the next with probability *1-restart_prob* or restart the walker with probability *restart_prob*.

To understand the algorithm better you can look at how PageRank works.