# Vectorize random walk on graph to eliminate for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, networkx

I struggle to understand how to vectorize a random walk in 1-D, where the next step is given by the probability of the current step.

I am using this model :

```
class MarkovChain(object):
    def __init__(self, transition_matrix, states):
        """
        Initialize the MarkovChain instance.

        Parameters
        ----------
        transition_matrix: 2-D array
            A 2-D array representing the probabilities of change of 
            state in the Markov Chain.

        states: 1-D array 
            An array representing the states of the Markov Chain. It
            needs to be in the same order as transition_matrix.
        """
        #self.transition_matrix = np.atleast_2d(transition_matrix)
        self.transition_matrix = transition_matrix
        self.states = states
        self.index_dict = {self.states[index]: index for index in 
                           range(len(self.states))}
        self.state_dict = {index: self.states[index] for index in
                           range(len(self.states))}

    def next_state(self, current_state):
        """
        Returns the state of the random variable at the next time 
        instance.

        Parameters
        ----------
        current_state: str
            The current state of the system.
        """

        #if else condition is to return the correct type for the transition matrix:
        # a scipy sparse matrix, or a numpy array

        if isinstance(transition_matrix, scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix):
          probs = self.transition_matrix[self.index_dict[current_state], :].A.reshape(-1)
        else:
           probs = self.transition_matrix[self.index_dict[current_state], :].A1

        probs /= probs.sum()

        return np.random.choice(
         self.states, 
         p= probs
        )

    def generate_states(self, current_state, no=10):
        """
        Generates the next states of the system.

        Parameters
        ----------
        current_state: str
            The state of the current random variable.

        no: int
            The number of future states to generate.
        """
        future_states = [current_state]

        for i in range(no):
            next_state = self.next_state(current_state)
            future_states.append(next_state)
            current_state = next_state
        return future_states
```

I would like to speed up the last function, or eventually refactor the code so to have directly a generated random walk of `n` steps.

Note that the next state is not uniformly chosen at random, but it is chosen at a probability `p` (Not sure if technically this is a correlated random walk ).

My objective is to get the path of states of the walk, possibly avoiding to use a for loop.

NOTE : I can related the model to this answer [Get node list from random walk in networkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311651/get-node-list-from-random-walk-in-networkx) , and borrowing from it, being **T** the transition matrix:

```
the first step (walk) can be evaluated as p^(1) = T p^(0).
Iteratively, the k-th random walk step can be evaluated as p^(k) = T p^(k-1).
```

Still, above answer use a for loop:

```
visited = list()
for k in range(walkLength):
    # evaluate the next state vector
    p = numpy.dot(T,p)
    # choose the node with higher probability as the visited node
    visited.append(numpy.argmax(p))
```

How could I vectorise the walk, since all next steps depends on the choice of current steps?

Comment: You nailed it. There's nothing to vectorise, as there is a dependency chain. But the trick is that 'vectorised operations' are just loops written by someone else in a lower level language. So your best chance is to check if someone else already did that for your problem - or do it yourself ;).

Comment: If you want `visited` there's not much help for you as far as vectorizing.  If you want it all in one step, you can do `p = numpy.dot(numpy.linalg.matrix_power(T, walkLength), p)`

Comment: HA! These kind of comments in a way are comforting for the self esteme to have nailed a not so easy one. ahah. Thank you lilborm.

@DanielF would you like to explain what it does and expected computation time ?

Generally speaking, I thought maybe the most of time is spent for using a list() structure, but actually complexity is O(1). Do you guys have comments where I might see a way for improvement - I am using a dict() to get the probability states, and list() to generate the dependency chain. using scipy sparse matrix is fastest thing I could do (I thought).